# Launch interactive ssh from nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a text blob that contains ip, port, user and passord and would like to write a small utility script where I can:

- paste the text in stdin
- extract the connection details using regex or any other means
- use node to launch ssh interactively using my parsed values

How would I launch the ssh command from node with the arguments, exit node and continue on ssh'ing? The documentation I've found regarding i.e. child_process concerns launching and controlling the process within node, but I simply want to exit back and take over once ssh is started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will fit your requirements, adjust it to your needs. The program does the following:

- reads the `port` from a file
- prompts you for the hostname, reading data from `stdin`
- launches `ssh` using `child_process.fork`

Code:

```
var port = require('fs').readFileSync('port.txt');

const rl = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Enter hostname: ', (answer) => {
  require('child_process').spawn('ssh', [answer, port],
    {stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]});
});
```

The question is answered except for the following point:

> exit node and continue on ssh'ing

I am not aware of this being possible in any programming language, but a better answer can correct me. Instead, you launch a child process and redirect all input/output to it. From your perspective, you only interact with `ssh`, so the fact that the `node` process still exists as a parent to `ssh` is transparent to you.

An equivalent command in `perl` for example would be `system("ssh");`